# How do i abort an ongoing rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

After a computer restart, when I check the status of a project, I see this output :

```
$ git status
On branch dev
No commands done.
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   squash 4fd089c <redacted: 1 month old commit message>
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch '<redacted: deleted branch>' on '1141b14'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

How do I clear that message? The app is at the same commit stage locally and on the remote repository, and there will never be a need to "amend" or "continue" with this.

Comment: You are in an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive) state - So if you are really sure you don't want to do anything then `git rebase --abort`

Comment: the problem is, that command reverted a full month of commits.

Comment: I pulled the source back from the remote repository and everything is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive) state.

So if you are really sure you don't want to do anything then `git rebase --abort` does the trick.